# Apache Error: No matching DirectoryIndex

Tags: php, apache, laravel

It's the first time I'm trying to deploy my **Laravel** App on my shared hosting account.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
|--laravel
  |--app
     |--GoPublic.php // use to point to new location 
  |--bootstrap
  |--config
  |--database
  // more folders 
|--public_html
  |--app // my subdomain document root
     |--assets
     |--index.php // GoPublic.php point to this file
```

When I go to my subdomain url, I get this:

[image]
I've checked my error.log file and I get the following 403 forbidden error:

```
[autoindex:error] [pid 910782] [] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/user/public_html/app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,Index.html,Index.htm,index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.phtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: You've torn apart the Laravel directory structure. /public/index.php is the entry point for the webserver. With what you have, it's so specific to your environment there's not much anyone can say to help.

Comment: What should I do to solve this?

Comment: You want to keep the structure of Laravel the same and point your subdomain to /laravel/public/.

Comment: I get the same error when I pointed to /laravel/public/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's late to answering but,
Make sure that you have the right permission on your `public/index.php` file.
For example, if your user is **core**, you should set it as the owner of `index.php` too.

To change it you can use this command:

`sudo chown -R core public/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `.htaccess` in the `laraval` directory and `laravel/public` directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
WriteEngine On
RewriteBase /laravel/public/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe you also need to point Laravel to a public directory to make it work. For example, if you've installed Laravel in `/path_to_laravel/public/` directory, you need to use these settings in your Apache config:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel/public/"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel/public/">
```

After that restart Apache and your app should work as expected.